# Render issue in Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering

[image]

this is my render image.

[image]

and this is viewport image. what i want to ask is to know what happend to this.

render image is pretty messy:(

is there some mistakes i did? i don't know exactly.. but one thing i would say is that it supposed to be rendered like viewport!

if anyone know about this issue, please help me. thanks:)

Comment: What does it look like in the viewport from camera view when you pres Numpad 0?

Comment: same like render image:)

Comment: Check camera clipping values in the Properties Edotor, Camera tab. Set near clipping to something low.

Comment: oh god.. it works after restart !!! thanks for your attention :)